# Cannot run adb from terminal in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, adb

I am new to Ubuntu. I cannot run `adb` in my terminal. When I try to run `adb` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
No command 'adb' found
```

At the same time I can run my Android application in the emulator.  What can be the problem?

Comment: Note that there are some knows issues about adb missing when somebody updated the SDK to 2.3, not sure if it's also the case of a fresh install of 2.3. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=adb+missing+2.3

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8580694/adb-doesnt-run-on-ubuntu-64-command-not-found.

Answer (score 9):

That means adb is not in the PATH.

If adb is in the current directory, try `./adb` instead.

the following command will show you the PATH: `echo $PATH`

Comment: not necessarily, since it might be SDK related. see my comment above.

Answer (score 7):

The command `adb` isn't on your path.

If you installed Android SDK manually, go to SDK install directory, then `platform-tools`. `adb` should be there.

If you didn't install the SDK at all, well, there's your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

Everything will be done for you .

Answer (score 2):

The adb application is 32 bit, trying to run it on a 64 bit machine wont work until you have installed the 32 bit libraries, you can grab them by typing:

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs

Quite a big download but should get you up and running!

Answer (score 0):

Even if I am in the platform-tools where the adb file is there I am giving ./adb still its telling command not found .

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop adb file to terminal. 
You can execute one command at a times, if you want next command to be executed